CSS font-feature-settings issues in Safari
I cannot figure out why I'm unable to get OpenType small caps to work correctly in Safari. Neither
font-feature-settings: "smcp";

nor
font-variant-caps: small-caps;

work correctly – "feature" does nothing and "variant-caps" just produces false small caps rather than those defined in the font. Both of these work correctly in Chrome and Firefox. I can't find any information to suggest that these ought to not work in Safari (Ver 18.0.1) and lots of information to suggest that they are supported.

Could you link to the font?

Please add a minimal reproducible example. It's impossible to give any advice without seeing your current CSS (especially the @font-face rules). Please clarify if this problem occurs only on mobile devices (so iOS safari) or using safari on the same device as Chrome/Firefox. If this error only occurs on mobile device you may not load the font correctly and see a local version on desktop browsers

You may also try the snippet from this post. I tested this on ios safari (albeit an older version). If you can't see true small caps you may also file a webkit bug report
